# Ambigious semantics for by-name parameters?

Tags: scala

Consider the following function:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

def callable[T]( operation: =>T) : Callable[T] = {
  new Callable[T] {
    def call : T = operation
  }
}
```

In the REPL, this code does what I want:

```
scala> val myCallable = callable {
     | println("Side effect!");
     | "Hi!"
     | }
myCallable: java.util.concurrent.Callable[String] = $anon$1@11ba4552

scala> myCallable.call
Side effect!
res3: String = Hi!

scala> myCallable.call
Side effect!
res4: String = Hi!
```

The by-name parameter is not evaluated until the function 'call' is called, and is re-evaluated every time that function is called. That is the behavior I want.

But in the [spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), it says the following about by-name parameters:

"the corresponding argument is not evaluated at the point of function application, but instead is evaluated at each use within the function."

From this description, it is unclear that I can rely on the behavior I want. What does a "use within the function mean"? How do I know that this refers to the point at which my Callable is called (sometime in the indefinite future), rather than the point at which it's defined (very much "within the function")?

The code is doing what I want. But I'd rest easier if I was sure this behavior is reliable, not a bug that might be "fixed" in some future version of scala.

Comment: FWIW, this is the way it is "supposed" to work so if there is a bug it is in the specification not the implementation.  But I am not certain that the spec adequately specifies that this is what is to happen--in particular, that "Side effect" is run every time.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug - that behaviour is as intended. You can think of "evaluated at each use within the function" recursively as "evaluated at each use within an expression in the function when that expression is evaluated".

Answer (score 2):

"The function" is the function you're passing your parameter to. What this passage tries to warn you about is this:

```
scala> def byName(arg: => String) = arg + arg
byName: (arg: => String)java.lang.String

scala> byName({println("hi") ; "foo" })
hi
hi
res0: java.lang.String = foofoo
```

i.e. your side effect will happen every time you reference the argument. Since you're only doing it once, that's not that relevant to your case (except for the point of evaluation, which is inside the function, not at the call site).

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the previous answers and clarify the way to avoid this, you can capture the value in a val inside the function if you only want it to be evaluated once.  By doing this you are causing evaluation of the "by name" parameter and are using the computed value more than once rather than causing 2 evaluations of the same expression.

```
scala> def byName(arg: => String) = {val computedArg = arg; computedArg + computedArg}
byName: (arg: => String)java.lang.String

scala> byName({"println("hi") ; "foo" })
hi
res0: java.lang.String = foofoo
```

In case you need to do that in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Lastly, to get truly *lazy* evaluation of a method parameter (zero or one evaluations only), you can do this:

```
def m1(i: => Int) = {
  lazy val li = i
  ...
  // any number of static or dynamic references to li
  ...
}
```